# What am i doing wrong? XML and bash

Tags: xml, bash, xpath

This is code i am trying to make work:

```
echo "type in code"
read code1
echo (xmllint --xpath '/rates/currency[code="$code1"]/rate/text()' rates.xml)
```

It prints "XPath set is empty"
It is supposed to print out the rate from my xml document. Which rate to print is determined by currency code (AUD, USD, EUR etc.). If it would be typed like that:

```
echo (xmllint --xpath '/rates/currency[code="GBP"]/rate/text()' rates.xml)
```

It would echo the correct rate for the currency which code is GBP.

Why is that? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes around the query string so that `$code` gets expanded to its value inside the string:

```
echo $(xmllint --xpath "/rates/currency[code=\"$code1\"]/rate/text()" rates.xml)
```

Comment: Thank you, helped a lot. Now ran into another simple problem (i am quite new in scripting). How do i multiply the following line by let's say 3?

    $(xmllint --xpath '/rates/currency['code="\"$code1\""']/rate/text()' rates.xml)

Comment: @user2939526 You're welcome. Just open a new question for that and it will be answered most likely.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange the quote delimiters `xmllint --xpath "/rates/currency[code='$code1']/rate/text()" rates.xml`.

Comment: Thank you, helped a lot. Now ran into another simple problem (i am quite new in scripting). How do i multiply the following line by let's say 3?

    $(xmllint --xpath '/rates/currency['code="\"$code1\""']/rate/text()' rates.xml)